# How do I restore a quarantined object in Kaspersky Anti-Virus 2012?

Tags: anti-virus, kaspersky

I normally know how to do this. From the main program window you just click on the *Quarantine* button from the lower part of the window.

There are two tabs in the new window that appears, one is *Quarantine* and one is *Storage*. I think the Quarantine tab lists objects that the user adds manually to the quarantine, and the Storage tab lists objects that the program adds when an infection is detected.

But the problem is that the *Restore* button is greyed out so I can't click on it. Why is that?

To give you an idea of what the dialog box looks like, see the link below.

[What is Quarantine in Kaspersky Anti-Virus 2012?](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208284634)

I have totally 8 objects under the Storage tab and none under the Quarantine tab. All of these objects have been added here by the program. They all have the Restore button active when I mark them except for 2 of them where the button is greyed out.

The file I want to restore was not stored on the system partition, so I don't have a shadow copy of it, and I don't keep a backup of this partition.

The quarantined objects are stored at `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Kaspersky Lab\AVP12\QB` and I have precisely 8 files there, which is the same number as shown in the dialog. They have the KLQ file extension.

This means that the file is not completely lost, but it is saved in a format that is not easy to restore from. But why is the Restore button greyed out for some of the files in the program dialog, but not for all of them?

[Where are the quarantine and the backup located? In what format are the files stored there?](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208284709)

Not all of the detected files are malicious programs. How do I restore these files? If not from the program dialog, how do I restore them from the Kaspersky binary format?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can just delete the first 52 bytes in the quarantine file and you will restore the original file with that. it seems that the scanner adds a small header of this size to the file.

worked for me to restore two zip files.